Recover local files of deleted Chromebook account
The Google account (institutional) associated with a user on the Chromebook was deleted.
When I go to login to the account now, it still prompts for me to login.
I can't do that anymore because the Google account doesn't exist.
Is it still possible to recover local files?

So you want to restore an institutional account, I assume, it wasn’t your account. If you’re unable to release the device ownership. You should probably request a refund on the device. We cannot help you restore files belonging to an account that wasn’t originally yours.

@Ramhound It was my account. But my account doesn't exist anymore. The device is owned by my personal account. I switched to my institutional account while attending the institution.

In my experience, most Chromebook devices can be configured to encrypt user files. If you are unable to log into your account because the account is deleted, then your user profile on the device and the data associated with the profile were also deleted.
